# Inspect Element after clicking

Tags: javascript, automation

So I've got some tedious work that needs to be done at work. I am trying to figure out a way to automate it. Let's say there are 500 times I need to repeat the following steps for 500 entries.

1. Click on a little arrow next to entry 1. This brings up a sub-menu

[little arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg7Cg.png)
[sub-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPJH5.jpg)

2. Then I want to click on "Share"
3. Then I want to do something on that page and so on.

So I begin by right-clicking and selecting 'Inspect Element' on chrome, and then I type Javascript in the console like `document.getElementsByClassName("userDropDownMenuBtn")[1].click()`

**The problem is that after I do this and get the sub-menu to open up,     I now need to right click and select 'Inspect Element' inside that       sub-menu to be able to do something like**       `document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem hasLink")[2].click()`.

The fact that I need to right click and Inspect Element again prevents me from being able to automate this completely. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't simply type in both of the statements without inspecting anything? Or does the second line change every time? If so, perhaps you could try to find out the pattern and react accordingly.

Comment: When I type the second statement, I get an error. So after I type `document.getElementsByClassName("userDropDownMenuBtn")[1].click()`, if I type the next line immediately after, I get an error which is basically that `document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem hasLink")` is 'None'... it can't find that element till I right click and inpect element on the little sub-menu that opens up.

Comment: That's strange. Can you find out what the last click triggers? Is it a link which you could craft or a button click which calls some javascript function?